# How to add an element to the first row of a div which contains some elements (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery

I have some elements as below:

```
<div id="shareswrapper">
    <div id="41">
           some content blah blah blah...
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to add lets say the below div to `shareswrapper`:

```
    <div id="1751">
           Some new content here!!!!
    </div>
```

The output would as below:

```
<div id="shareswrapper">
    <div id="1751">
           Some new content here!!!!
    </div>
    <div id="41">
           some content blah blah blah...
    </div>
</div>
```

I used first child but gain no success. `.before()` method wont work for me because I don't know which divs I have inside the shareswrapper.
Any suggestion?

Comment: It's not valid to start an ID with a number prior to HTML5 and will not be supported.

Comment: you might consider using a custom data-id or something like that..

Comment: Building a bit on what Ohgodwhy said: Perhaps more importantly, `id` values starting with digits are [invalid in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) even though they're valid in HTML5 and tolerated (though invalid) in HTML4. Since jQuery uses CSS selectors when you want to interact with elements, it's best to stick to CSS's rules for them. jQuery will try to use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, but when they fail (and on a standards browser, they will with a selector containing an all-numeric ID), it has to fall back to it's own searching code.

Comment: What about reading the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the tip, I'll certainly take that into consideration.

Comment: @bažmegakapa The problem was I didn't have any idea what to look for

Comment: @ علیرضا: It's well worth reading through [the API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It takes about an hour, maybe two, and it pays you back *dramatically* in no time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use prepend..

```
$('#shareswrapper').prepend('<div id="1751">Some new content here!!!!</div>');
```

Comment: Aha, mistaken then.. Voting up.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with both. Chain them together

```
$('#shareswrapper:first-child').before("injection content")
```

Comment: This is needlessly roundabout. Would also fail if the container were empty, where `prepend` will work (granted the OP didn't show an empty container).

Comment: -1 this does not work. Will inject before the main container (`#sharescontainer`) if it is the first child of its parent. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/3gTgP/). Who upvoted this?

Comment: @bažmegakapa ouch yuo are correct. I am thoroughly chagrined.